# How drap / drop an item in Grid layout (use cdk ) in angular

Tags: angular

I built an item drag/drop functionality in a grid layout in angular (cdk used). Currently I just drag/drop and change the position between those items, can't drag and drop to a position without the item (It won't find the dropIndex so it can't drop it to a position without the item). Can anyone help me find a solution that can drag/drop anywhere in the grid?

DEMO:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-sortable-flex-wrap-v2-hz5ke7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can you please elaborate your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710294/cdk-drag-drop-does-not-correctly-change-the-position-of-images/60712759#60712759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need your items to be moved in to empty slots right. Can you check following modification I did.

What I did was adding **visibility: hidden**  property for defining empty slots. This way we will still have a empty item slot to drag and drop with a dropIndex.

```
  <div
    cdkDropList
    *ngFor="let item of items"
    [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="dropListEnterPredicate"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="dropListDropped($event)"
  >
    <!-- <div cdkDrag class="example-box" (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)">
      {{ item }}
    </div> -->
    <div 
      cdkDrag
      class="example-box" 
      [ngClass]="emptyItems.includes(item)? 'empty-slot' : ''"
      (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)">
    {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Checkout the complete [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid-72a34i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Note it is a two column grid. Hope you can follow similar approach to make your grid work.