How can I implement darg and drop for 2D array in Angular?
i have below objects
 columns: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
 rows: string[] = ['1', '2', '3'];
 data: any[][] = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['P', 'Q', 'R'],
    ['S', 'T', 'U'],
]

`with this i have showing table which have a, b, c is header of table and 1,2,3 is header of table rows just like excel.so it will display 3*3 columns and row like shown below
A   B   C 

1   A   B   C
2   P   Q   R
3   S   T   U`
'now i need implement drag functionality where user can drag any cell and drop anywhere within this table. `
<div class="table-content">
            <div *ngFor="let row of data;let rowIndex = index" class="row">
                <div class="row-header">
                    <div class="row-font-weight">{{ rows[rowIndex] }}</div>
                </div>
                    <div class="cell" *ngFor="let col of columns; let colIndex = index">
                        <div  style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                            <div class="area-header">
                                <span class="area-header-lbl">areas</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell-content">
                                <div class="add-area">
                                    <span class="Add-icon">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                {{data[rowIndex][colIndex]}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


Hi new contributor :) There are a infinite amount of possibilities here. You have to specifiy what you want. You want plain javascript code? Is a library ok? You using a UI framework already, like ngMaterials or PrimeNG?

It's a bit old and I don't know if is updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710294/cdk-drag-drop-does-not-correctly-change-the-position-of-images/60712759#60712759 (read also the comments)

i am using angular framework and using angular cdk drag drop
